# Issue with JSOn parsing - in Array

Tags: json, parsing

I am getting the data from DB as array and then outputting them as a JSON.

Some parts of my code:

```
 private function getUsers( ){
    $users = $this->db->resource(dbMapper::USER);
 return $this->usersToArray( $users );}

 private function usersToArray( $users ){
        $result = array( );
        foreach ($users as $user){
            $result[] = array(
                'id'            => intval( $user->get('id') ),
                'name'          => $user->get('name')
            );
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllData( ){ 
        $result = array( );
        $result['users'] = $this->getUsers( );
        $results = print_r($result['users'], true); echo $results;
        return $result;
    }
```

**and then I get the JSON from this result:**

```
  $data = $model->getAllData( );
        $this->_helper->json( $data );
```

The JSON output looks like this (I removed the data for debugging), but even if there are no data I have a syntax error in first letter of Array:

In my browser I got this: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data**

and if I put that JSOn to JSON validator, I got this:

**Parse error on line 1:
Array(    [0] => A
^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
        )
```

Not sure what is wrong with the Array in JSON...

Comment: can you show sample json in which you try to perform operation

Comment: ah I found the issue - the problem was in DB - there was a username with bad encoding (strange characters) and it caused the JSON error. i am closing this, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with incorrect characters in the username field in DB, that caused the JSON error.